# Groupby of different columns with different aggreagation with cumsum for next date

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, cumsum

I have a dataframe sorted by date and time as :

```
 ID     Date     Time      A         B      C
 abc   06/Feb     11       12        12     10 
 abc   06/Feb     12       14        13     5
 xyz   07/Feb      1       16        14     50
 xyz   07/Feb      2       18        15     0
 xyz   07/Feb      3       20        16     10
```

I want to groupby it by ID and Date and get sum as Numerator,count as Denominator but for next date the sum will be cumsum of previous dates and so will be the count as cumcount, and 3 more columns of last value of A,B,C columns will be added.Such as:

```
ID    Date     A_Num  A_denom   B_Num   B_Denom  C_Num   C_Denom  A_Last  B_Last  C_Last
abc   06/Feb    26       2        25       2      15        2       14      13      5
xyz   07/Feb    54       3        45       3      60        3       20      16      10
```

I am not able to perform all these in one go..Can anyone help me in this.Thanks in advance.

Now I want to add df2 in df1 acc to id as:

```
ID    Date     A_Num  A_denom   B_Num   B_Denom  C_Num   C_Denom  A_Last  B_Last  C_Last
abc   06/Feb    52       4        50       4      30        4       14      13      5
xyz   07/Feb    108      6        90       6      120       6       20      16      10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate `sum`, `size` and `last` per groups in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html), then selecting `num` and `denum` and use cumulative sum and last add by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) another DataFrame created by aggregate [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
cols = ['A','B','C']

print (df[cols].dtypes)
A    int64
B    int64
C    int64
dtype: object

d = {'sum':'Num','size':'denom'}
df1 = df.groupby(['ID','Date'])[cols].agg(['sum','size']).rename(columns=d).cumsum()
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')

df2 = df.groupby(['ID','Date'])[cols].last().add_suffix('_Last')
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).reset_index()

print (df3)
    ID    Date  A_Num  A_denom  B_Num  B_denom  C_Num  C_denom  A_Last  \
0  abc  06/Feb     26        2     25        2     15        2      14   
1  xyz  07/Feb     80        5     70        5     75        5      20   

   B_Last  C_Last  
0      13       5  
1      16      10
```

For write to file without index use:

```
df3.to_csv('file', index=False)
```

If there is no `.reset_index` in solution use:

```
df3.to_csv('file')
```

Comment: Hi,I tried this but i am getting an error at your second last line i.e df.loc[;,pd.IndexSlice.....
The error is TypeError: Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @naina - Hmm, so it means there are some columns not numeric. Added solution for filter columns for processing in `cols`

Comment: Yeah they have float values. Should i try chnaging their type using astype(float)?

Comment: @naina - So if check `print (df[cols].dtypes)` there are floats? Not `object` ?

Comment: @jezreal - it was float64 and changing the type worked..thanks alot..but one issue is coming when i am writing it into csv file..ID and Date are not getting written down in the file.Can you suggest soemthing for that

Comment: @naina - What is your code for write to file?

Comment: Yeah i was writing index=False so it was not coming.Big Thanks :)

Comment: can i get the answer by id here with date

Comment: @naina - same solution, only remove `.cumsum()`

Comment: df = df_org.groupby(['ID'])[cols].agg(['sum','size','last']).rename(columns=d)
df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, ['Num', 'denom']]] = df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, ['Num', 'denom']]]

I am using this..is it okay?

Comment: @naina - yes, exaclty.

Comment: Actually it was df2 should be added in df1 acc to id