# Groupby of different columns with different aggreagation with cumsum with another dataset

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, cumsum

I have a dataframe sorted by date and time as :
df1:

```
ID    Date     A_sum  A_count   B_sum   B_count  A_last  B_last  
abc   01/jan    26       2        25       2       0      0
xyz   01/jan    54       3        45       3       4      6
```

df2:

```
ID     Date     Time      A         B
abc   02/jan     11       10        10 
abc   02/jan     12       14        13
xyz   02/jan      1       26        24
xyz   02/jan      2       18        15
xyz   02/jan      3       20        16
```

I want to append these two dfs on id and want to update df2 as output as:

```
ID    Date     A_sum             A_count    B_sum   B_count  A_last  B_last  
abc   02/jan  50 #26+10+14        4 #2+2     48       4      14      13
xyz   02/jan  118 #54+26+18+20    6 #3+3    100       6      20      16
```

So it is taking the previous value of columns from df1 and adding it in df2

Comment: Date is not important?

Comment: no it is not...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and *[`named aggregation`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html)* to transform `df2` to the same layout as `df1` and then append the result to `df1`, followed by another round of `groupby()` and aggregation, as follows:

```
df3 = (df2.groupby(['ID', 'Date'], as_index=False, sort=False)
          .agg(A_sum=('A', 'sum'), A_count=('A', 'count'), 
               B_sum=('B', 'sum'), B_count=('A', 'count'), 
               A_last=('A', 'last'), B_last=('B', 'last'))
      )

df_out = (df1.append(df3)
             .groupby('ID', as_index=False)
             .agg({'Date': 'last', 
                   'A_sum': 'sum', 'A_count': 'sum', 
                   'B_sum': 'sum', 'B_count': 'sum', 
                   'A_last': 'last', 'B_last': 'last'})
         )
```

Result:

```
print(df_out)


    ID    Date  A_sum  A_count  B_sum  B_count  A_last  B_last
0  abc  02/jan     50        4     48        4      14      13
1  xyz  02/jan    118        6    100        6      20      16
```

Comment: i have 40 columns and it is giving syntax error as i used 
for i in cols:
df3 = (df2.groupby(['ID', 'Date'], as_index=False).agg(i+'_Num'=(i, 'sum'),i+'_denom'=(i,'count'),i+'_last'=(i, 'last'))
final = (df1.append(df3).groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg({i+'_Num':'sum',i+'_denom':'sum', i+'_Last': 'last'}))

Comment: i is column name

Comment: @naina  If you want it to use in a loop for all columns, you can't use this syntax then.  Since for named aggregation, it's a variable name on the left of `=` instead of a string.  Also, you will then have discrete aggregation results that is difficult to use.

Comment: @naina  In that case, you might need to fall back to the solution of defining columns one by one like the other solution.  Sorry, as I got some urgent duties now.  you may have to ask for the help of the other solution poster how to modify his/her solution to suit your need.

Answer (score 1):

Slighlty lenghty way

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from io import StringIO
>>>
>>> df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""ID    Date     A_sum  A_count   B_sum   B_count  A_last  B_last
... abc   01/jan    26       2        25       2       0      0
... xyz   01/jan    54       3        45       3       4      6"""), sep="\s+")
>>>
>>>
>>> df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""ID     Date     Time      A         B
... abc   02/jan     11       10        10
... abc   02/jan     12       14        13
... xyz   02/jan      1       26        24
... xyz   02/jan      2       18        15
... xyz   02/jan      3       20        16"""), sep="\s+")
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> df2["A_sum"]   = df2.groupby("ID")["A"].transform("sum")
>>> df2["A_count"] = df2.groupby("ID")["A"].transform("count")
>>> df2["A_last"]  = df2.groupby("ID")["A"].transform("last")
>>>
>>> df2["B_sum"]   = df2.groupby("ID")["B"].transform("sum")
>>> df2["B_count"] = df2.groupby("ID")["B"].transform("count")
>>> df2["B_last"]  = df2.groupby("ID")["B"].transform("last")
>>>
>>> del df2["Time"]
>>> del df2["A"]
>>> del df2["B"]
>>>
>>> df2 = df2.groupby("ID").apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-1])
>>>
>>> df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
>>>
>>> df3.groupby('ID').agg({"Date": 'last', 'A_sum': 'sum', 'B_sum' : 'sum', 'A_count': 'sum', 'B_count': 'sum', 'A_last': 'last', 'B_last': 'last'})
       Date  A_sum  B_sum  A_count  B_count  A_last  B_last
ID
abc  02/jan     50     48        4        4      14      13
xyz  02/jan    118    100        6        6      20      16
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in cols:
   df3 = (df2.groupby(['ID', 'Date'], as_index=False).agg(i+'_Num'=(i, 'sum'),i+'_denom'=(i,'count'),i+'_last'=(i, 'last'))
   final = (df1.append(df3).groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg({i+'_Num':'sum',i+'_denom':'sum', i+'_Last': 'last'}))
But it is not working
```

Comment: If this is a clarification to your question, please edit the question itself and add it there. If this is a solution, please state that clearly here.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/67800033/2901002
cols = ['A','B']

df11 = df2.groupby(['ID','Date'])[cols].agg(['sum','count'])
df11.columns = df11.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')

df22 = df2.groupby(['ID','Date'])[cols].last().add_suffix('_last')

df3 = pd.concat([df11, df22], axis=1).reset_index(level=1)
print (df3)
       Date  A_sum  A_count  B_sum  B_count  A_last  B_last
ID                                                         
abc  02/jan     24        2     23        2      14      13
xyz  02/jan     64        3     55        3      20      16
```

Filter only columns from `df1` for sum:

```
df33 = df1.filter(regex='ID|_sum|count').set_index('ID')
print (df33)
     A_sum  A_count  B_sum  B_count
ID                                 
abc     26        2     25        2
xyz     54        3     45        3
```

Join together, `sum` and assign missing `date` if necessary:

```
df = pd.concat([df3, df33]).sum(level=0).astype(int).assign(Date = df3['Date']).set_index('Date', append=True).reset_index()
print (df)
    ID    Date  A_sum  A_count  B_sum  B_count  A_last  B_last
0  abc  02/jan     50        4     48        4      14      13
1  xyz  02/jan    118        6    100        6      20      16
```

Comment: i am not able to understand this line..  
df33 = df1.filter(regex='ID|_sum|count').set_index('ID')                                              
the actual names are A_Num,A_denom,B_Num,B_denom

Comment: @naina - It filter only all columns with `_sum` or `_count` or `ID` susbtrings

Comment: @naina - Because only these columns are important for sum to `df3`

Comment: df33 = df2.filter(regex='ID|_Num|_denom').set_index('ID')       
will bwe my code,right?

Comment: @naina - yes, exactly.

Comment: sum and count columns are not coming in the output

Comment: I am not able to get sum and count columns in the output.it is just giving back the _Last columns

Comment: @naina - sorry, meeting. So `df33 = df1.filter(regex='ID|_sum|count').set_index('ID')` not working for you? there are different columsnnames like mentioned in question?

Comment: No 
df = pd.concat([df3, df33]).sum(level=0).astype(int).assign(Date = df3['Date']).set_index('Date', append=True).reset_index()
this is not working..i hv sent u my code in message

Comment: no error is coming...the last line of code is giving just columns ending with _Last along with ID and DATE

Comment: @naina - If use `pd.concat([df3, df33]).sum(level=0)` it is expected ouput? next code is for appedn column `date`

Comment: but still at the end only id,date and columns of last value are coming

Comment: @naina - OK, so `print (df33)`  return `ID` and all `count` and all `sum` columns?

Comment: they are coming...if i jz concat the df3,df33 then also i am getting all columns but as i have the problem statement of adding the sum and count it is not happening

Answer (score 0):

You can concat both the df's and then you can use `groupby`:

```
cols = df1.columns
df1 = df1[['ID','Date','A_sum', 'B_sum']]
df2 = df2.drop('Time', 1)
df1.columns = df2.columns
merged_df  = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(['ID']).agg({'A' : [sum , 'count', 'last'], 'B' : [sum , 'count', 'last'], 'Date': 'last'})
merged_df.columns = merged_df.columns.map('_'.join)
```

OUTPUT:

```
     A_sum  A_count  A_last  B_sum  B_count  B_last Date_last
ID                                                           
abc     50        3      14     48        3      13    02/jan
xyz    118        4      20    100        4      16    02/jan
```

Comment: A_count should be 2+2 = 4,3+3 = 6